# R data table one field without aggregation

Tags: r

I have used data.table functionality to find out the minimum of "y" by "x" as shown in the code below.

```
> x <- c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A")
> y <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
> z <- c(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3)
> df <- data.table(x, y, z)
> temp <- df[, .(M=min(y)), by="x"]
> temp
   x M
1: A 0
2: B 1
3: C 1
> df
   x y z
1: A 0 1
2: B 1 2
3: A 1 1
4: C 1 4
5: B 2 5
6: A 2 3
```

However, now after finding out the minimum, I want to be able to pull out the corresponding value of "z" for each of the "x"s.

In short, I want temp to be like so:

```
> temp
   x M z
1: A 0 1
2: B 1 2
3: C 1 4
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: Without calculating `temp` you can use `unique(df[order(y)], by = "x")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by a single step using `.I` to extract the row index of the logical vector and subset the rows of the dataset based on that

```
df[df[, .I[y==min(y)], by = x]$V1]
#    x y z
#1: A 0 1
#2: B 1 2 
#3: C 1 4
```

Or another option is

```
df[order(x,y)][!duplicated(x)]
```

---

If we want to get the output based on 'temp', use a join

```
df[temp,  on =.(x, y=M)]
#   x y z
#1: A 0 1
#2: B 1 2
#3: C 1 4
```

Comment: Can you please share where can I read up more on the syntax of .I?

Comment: @user3701522  You can read the vignettes of data.table from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).  It is also found in the `doc` folder in `data.table` in the `R` folder